# createTextNode surrounding my select list in unwanted quotation marks

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-applications

I want to add a select list to my website using a button. 
I need to use nodes because i need to be able to access it within the DOM so i can retrieve its value later on so I cant use innerHTML.

My problem is that createTextNode seems to surround my list in quotation marks and so it will not display. Can anyone help me out

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Pop Up </title>

<script>
function change()
{
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("dropDownList");
    var content = document.createTextNode("<select name='scrapbookID' id='scrapbookID'><option value='15'>one</option><option value='18'>two</option><option value='20'>three</option><option value='21'>four</option></select>");

    theDiv.appendChild(content);
}
</script>

<style type = "text/css">


</style>


</head>
<body>

    <div id = "signout">
        Your are Currently signed in.<br />
        <a href = "#" id = "signOutPHP">Sign Out</a>
         <div id = "dropDownList">
            <button onclick="change()">Add List</button>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to have is `.createElement()` it creates a given element, where as `createTextNode` creates text node with given content.

```
function change()
{
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("dropDownList");

    var select  = document.createElement('select');
    select.name = 'scrapbookID';
    select.id = 'scrapbookID';
    select.innerHTML = "<option value='15'>one</option><option value='18'>two</option><option value='20'>three</option><option value='21'>four</option>"

    theDiv.appendChild(select);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vMLNa/1/)

Answer (score 1):

When you’re creating a text node, it’s treated as exactly that: text, not HTML. But it’s cleaner to just build the DOM properly!

```
function change() {
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("dropDownList");

    var selectBox = document.createElement("select");
    selectBox.id = "scrapbookID";
    selectBox.name = "scrapbookID";

    var options = {
        "15": "one",
        "18": "two",
        "20": "three",
        "21": "four"
    };

    for(var x in options) {
        if(options.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = x;
            option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options[x]));

            selectBox.appendChild(option);
        }
    }

    theDiv.appendChild(selectBox);
}
```